# ol list counter reset based on start property using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, custom-lists

I need to make a jquery script that can take the OL start properly and transform it into a css based counter.
So for a html like this:

```
<ol >
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>
<p></p>
<ol start ="3" >
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>
```

should start the numbering from 3 on the second list using the css

```
OL { counter-reset: list 3 }
LI { display: block }
LI:before {
content: counter(item) ". ";
counter-increment: item;
display:block;
}
```

I'd like to add the counter reset automatically based on the start property.
What i got till now is :

```
$("ol").each(function() {

  var index = $("ol").prop("start")-1;
  $(this).css({counter-reset:list index});    

});
```

the index var is working but i don't know how to insert that inside the css property.

Answer (score 1):

We're doing this with JS because the surrounding CSS is hiding the default numbering. We have a CMS that is providing a start attribute:

If you did want to do it in JS, I'd suggest:

```
<ol >
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>
<p></p>
<ol start="3" >
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ol>
```

Then this CSS will recreate the numbering using :before

```
ol {
    counter-reset: li
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-increment:li;
}

li:before {
    content:" " counter(li) ". ";
}
```

and this JS will then apply the start attribute in conjunction with your styles:

```
$("ol").each(function(idx, el) {
  var index = parseInt($(el).attr("start"))-1;
    if (!isNaN(index)) {
        $(el).css({'counter-reset':'li ' + index});    
    }
});
```

as demonstrated here...

http://jsfiddle.net/sifriday/vt2nconp/2/

Comment: The problem was that because of the styling needed for the ol we can't use the list's default numbering that is affected by the start. And because the cms is automatically adding the start element to the list I'd like to use that to renumber the list styled with the css :before.

Comment: gotcha, i'll tweak my fiddle